# Prevent UITextView from auto-scrolling when when being resized through auto-layout

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextview

My view has a TextView with 0 as the number of lines, populated with a long text that the user can edit.
When the keyboard shows, to resize the TextView so that it fits in the visible portion of the screen, the height constraint of an empty view at the bottom of the screen is equaled to the keyboard height. The bottom of the textView is constrained to the top of the empty view, so the text view gets resized.

When this happens, the textView automatically scrolls down in the text. I would like the text to avoid this scrolling, so that the first line always stays visible. I have tried a few ways, such as:

- Disabling scrolling between keyboardWillShow and keyboardDidShow, not working
- Scrolling back to zero, but we can see the text scrolling down and then scrolling back up (textView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(location:0, length:0)))

Here's a drawing to make it much clearer (can't embed it yet, sorry):

[UITextView Drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYSYO.png)

Relevant code:

```
func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        let duration: TimeInterval = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).doubleValue
        emptyViewHeightConstraint.constant = keyboardSize.height
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() }
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    let duration: TimeInterval = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).doubleValue
    emptyViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() }
}
```

PS: The TextView is actually inside a StackView, and this StackView has its bottom constrained to the top of the empty view.

Comment: try this.. textView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect.zero, animated: false)

Comment: Thanks @iOSFreak, just tried but it unfortunately didn't work. I tried in keyboardWillShow and in didShow